# Returning List of SeqNbrs from Oracle stored procedure to C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm looking to get some help rewriting a procedure. I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong data types somewhere in here, so please let me know how i can improve the below.

I'm trying to go after the seq #s in this table:

```
create table myschema.file_path_table
(
  encrypt_file_path_seq_nbr NUMBER(15) not null,
  file_path                 VARCHAR2(1000)
)
```

I have this package created in oracle:

```
TYPE file_paths IS TABLE OF myschema.file_path_table.file_path%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE path_seq_nbrs IS TABLE OF myschema.file_path_table.encrypt_file_path_seq_nbr%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE GETFILEPATHSEQNBRS(IN_FILE_PATHS     IN FILE_PATHS,
                             OUT_FILE_PATH_SEQ OUT PATH_SEQ_NBRS) 
IS
    V_FILE_PATH     myschema.file_path_table.FILE_PATH%TYPE;
    V_FILE_PATH_SEQ myschema.file_path_table.ENCRYPT_FILE_PATH_SEQ_NBR%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF IN_FILE_PATHS.COUNT < 1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'in_file_paths.COUNT: ' || IN_FILE_PATHS.COUNT);
    END IF;
    FOR INDX IN 1 .. IN_FILE_PATHS.COUNT LOOP
        GETFILEPATHSEQNBR(IN_FILE_PATHS(INDX), V_FILE_PATH_SEQ);
        OUT_FILE_PATH_SEQ(INDX) := V_FILE_PATH_SEQ;
    END LOOP;
END GETFILEPATHSEQNBRS;
```

The inner GETFILEPATHSEQNBR() does a lookup on file_path_table to get the sequence of the filepath, or inserts a new row there if the path doesn't currently have a sequence #. So I can't just bulk select the sequence #'s. Are my variables IN_FILE_PATHS and OUT_FILE_PATH_SEQ the correct data type for what I'm trying to do? I feel like I'm off the mark here, is there an easier way?

Once all of the sequence numbers are gathered, I need to return this list to my C# app. That code looks like this:

```
private static void GetFilePathSeqNbrs(ref EncryptFilesTable table)
{
    IEnumerable<string> pathQuery = (from row in table.rowArray
                                     select row.path).Distinct();
    try
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("myschema.PKG_ENCRYPT.GETFILEPATHSEQNBRS", EncryptUtils.connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.BindByName = true;

            OracleParameter p_out_values = new OracleParameter();
            p_out_values.ParameterName = "OUT_FILE_PATH_SEQ";
            p_out_values.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
            p_out_values.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            p_out_values.Size = pathQuery.Count();
            p_out_values.Value = pathQuery.ToArray();
            p_out_values.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_out_values);

            OracleParameter p_in_values = new OracleParameter();
            p_in_values.ParameterName = "IN_FILE_PATHS";
            p_in_values.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            p_in_values.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            p_in_values.Size = pathQuery.Count();
            p_in_values.Value = pathQuery.ToArray();
            p_in_values.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_in_values);

            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);  //the datatable here is always empty.

            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (System.Data.DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Console.Write(dr[dc].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        EncryptUtils.Log(Const.LogMsgType.Error, e.GetBaseException().ToString());
    }
}
```

Running this code set completes without errors, but my resulting data table is empty. If I run just the procedure through a test window in PL/SQL, it returns the OUT_FILE_PATH_SEQ's I expect. Why is my data table empty? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This seems a very complex solution for a relatively simple problem.  Are you trying to get the next sequence number so you can do an insert? Or trying to get the range of sequence numbers or....???

Comment: Later on, I am using the EncryptFilesTable, which is a UDT i have mapped to a different table called Encrypt_Files. I'm running a merge between EncryptFilesTable and Encrypt_Files. This UDT is missing these path seq's. I can't find a way to pass the UDT, update the seq's, and then run my merge. My solution was to get the seq's ahead of time. hope that makes sense...

Comment: Your solution will only work some of the time. Oracle caches a group of sequence numbers when a call to nextval occurs.  If a rollback occurs the group is discarded.   Why not use a global temporary table.  Insert your C# table data into it then merge into the destination table?

Comment: The merge is going to deal with 10-100 thousand rows , I don't think a temp table would be smart.

Comment: Look up global temporary tables in Oracle and you will see that they are perfect for your issue. See http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php

Comment: Will  do, I trust in the kevinsky. Thanks!